# Ceiling fan mounting bracket issue

Tags: ceiling-fan, junction-box

first time poster.  I need to replace a Casablanca ceiling fan in my house that we've owned for a year.  The house was custom built in 2002.   I bought a Hunter ceiling fan to replace the old one, but the holes in the junction box (which match the Casablanca fan) are too narrow for the Hunter mounting bracket.  Can someone take a look at the attached pic and make a suggestion as to what options I have?  I'm confident that the junction box was installed when the house was built and would be really surprised if the box wasn't rated for a ceiling fan.

Thanks

Stan[image]

Comment: That's strange...I take it there's a joist behind the middle of the box?

Comment: why are you telling us how long you have owned the house?

Comment: ThreePhaseEel, don't know.  Box is on the lower level so there's no attic access. Jsotola, wanted to make clear that we're not original owners so we have no knowledge as to how the box was installed.

Comment: That is a moist centered fan rated ceiling box. I installed one of these during my remodel 2 years ago. It is a standard mount, so I'm not sure what you mean by the mounting doesn't fit. Show picture of the fan mounting plate. The box shuld have 2 holes on each side. Looks like one is partially covered by ceiling texture.

Comment: Jeff, thanks. You're exactly right. The paint covered the holes I needed to use.  Thanks.

Comment: @StanMcFarland -- post that as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Comment: I believe the long wood screws for the Hunter bracket will go through holes in the box and deep into the ceiling joist. Screw these in *firm* but do not over-tighten. I don't think you would crack the box, but you could if you over-tightened by a lot. I have installed several of these fans but it has been some time. I think the instructions are to drill a pilot hole, but the instructions seem to err on the low side for the drill diameter. To make the screws go in easier I use wax on the screws to reduce the torque required to drive the screws.

Comment: @jeff Cates please make your comment an answer so the op can accept it and this could help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is a joist centered fan rated ceiling box. I installed one of these during my remodel 2 years ago. It is a standard mount, so I'm not sure what you mean by the mounting doesn't fit. Show picture of the fan mounting plate. The box should have 2 holes on each side. Looks like one is partially covered by ceiling texture. Your mounting bracket should have elongated holes also, to help center the bracket over the holes.

Answer (score 0):

First ascertain that the box is securely fastened to a building member.  Then drill holes and tap the back of the box to match the new bracket.